# Using two array values in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following loop:

```
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];

array.forEach(function(arr) {
  $(".department").append('<option value="' + array + '">' + textArray + '</option>');
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the `<option>` label to use the text but its value to use the `array` array.

If I do the following:

```
$(".filterSection .department").append('<option value="'+array+'">'+textArray+'</option>');
```

My output looks like this:

```
<option value="Value 1,Value 2,Value 3">Text 1</option>
<option value="Value 1,Value 2,Value 3">Text 2</option>
```

Whereas I'm looking for:

```
<option value="Value 1">Text 1</option>
<option value="Value 2">Text 2</option>
```

Comment: change `<option value="'+array+'">` to `<option value="'+arr+'">`

Comment: `array.forEach(function(item, i) {
  $(".department").append('<option value="' + item + '">' + textArray[i] + '</option>');
});`

Answer (score 2):

Using map and literal templating.

NOTE: The append will only perform one DOM update which is recommended
NOTE: It seems .join("") is not even needed in the append

```js
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"],
textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"],
options   = array.map((val,i) => `<option value="${val}">${textArray[i]}</option>`);  

$(".department").append(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="department">
<option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Speaking about performance, I'm not quite sure what's the reason, but `reduce()` [seem to perform much better](https://jsbench.me/60k6t3cqfd/1).

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I see an error is returned for the map example in your bench

Comment: Whatever I do I get error in the first code. Even when I swap yours and mine - Chrome 78

Comment: Can you try `const options = array.map(
    (val,i) => \`<option value="${val}">${textArray[i]}</option>\`
);
$('.department').append(options)` just for fun to see if the .append is happier with a separate append

Comment: That way it runs much faster

Comment: And it seems that concatenating resulting string gradually is also slowing down the `reduce()`

Answer (score 1):

Just take a plain `for` loop over the indices and take the elements from both arrays.

```
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"],
    textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $(".department").append('<option value="' + array[i] + '">' + textArray[i] + '</option>');
}
```

Comment: Wow. No map/reduce? So I for once [posted more ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60295641/295783) than you ;)))

Comment: yes, three times. if not wanted, a string with all options would help.

Comment: @NinaScholz bro, can you add me on discord so I can ask questions when I get stucked on JS. I'm currently a beginner and sometimes on Stackoverflow I paste too many codes in or get downvoted even after I do my research. I will pay you xd xd#4536. It would be convenient if I can have someone that can help me once in a while when I get confused.

Comment: @Elliot, acutally am not somehere else. you could stll ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the indexes while passing the array. Instead, you are passing the whole array.

```
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];

array.forEach(function(arr,index) {
  $(".department").append('<option value="' + arr + '">' + textArray[index] + '</option>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways that will give you the result that you want

```
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];

const options = Object.assign({}, ...array.map((key, index) => {
  return {
    [key]: textArray[index]
  };
}));

Object.keys(options).forEach(optionKey => {
   $(".department").append('<option value="' + optionKey + '">' + options[optionKey] + '</option>');
});
```

Another solution

```
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];

const options = Object.assign({}, ...array.map((key, index) => {
  return {
    [key]: textArray[index]
  };
}));

Object.entries(options).forEach(option => {
   $(".department").append('<option value="' + option[0] + '">' + option[1] + '</option>');
});
```

Comment: That is too much code for something as simple as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60295641/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan you are right, my answer is working but your answer is the best until now :)

however incoming questions I will keep trying to do my best to provide helpful answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `map` for creating an array of [`Option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) objects and then append that array to the desired element.

This is a dry approach, and also you can use the [`Option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option) object if you want to add some features/behavior, read the documentation for more detail.

```js
let array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
let textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];
$(".department").append(array.map((v, i) => new Option(textArray[i], v)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="department">
<option value="">Please select</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var html = '<option value="">default</option>';
var array = ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"];
var textArray = ["Text 1", "Text 2", "Text 3"];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  html += '<option value="' + array[i] + '"';

  html += '>' + textArray[i] + '</option>';

}

document.getElementById('select').innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<select name="HelmAtt1" id="select"></select>
```